# How to activate tap to route to Google Maps

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, geolocation

It says Google Map is not installed or is disabled. Google Map is installed. So somehow disabled. How can i use it in my project? This image will show you what i meant: [image]

Codes are here:

```
const double ZOOM = 1;

class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  static GoogleMapController? _googleMapController;
  Set<Marker> markers = Set();
  // ignore: prefer_final_fields, unused_field
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controllerGoogleMap = Completer();
  late GoogleMapController newGoogleMapController;

  late Position currentPosition;
  var geoLocator = Geolocator();
  double bottomPaddingOfMap = 0;

  void locatePosition() async {
    //USER CURRENT LOCATION
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    currentPosition = position;

    LatLng latLatPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition =
        // ignore: unnecessary_new
        new CameraPosition(target: latLatPosition, zoom: 14);
    newGoogleMapController
        .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
  }

       static const CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = const CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(40.7956, 29.4420),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  ); 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Location").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // ignore: avoid_print
          print(snapshot);
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            //Extract the location from document
            GeoPoint location = snapshot.data!.docs.first.get("location");
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the Google Maps package "com.google.android.apps.maps" in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest package="com.your.package">
  <queries>
    <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.maps" />
  </queries>
  ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: This is the answer, thanks a lot. I will give you the bounty :)

Answer (score 0):

If you hadn't use google map apis then create one api key on [GCP](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/start). After creating one api, use that in FLutter project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you use this package [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)
As with all the flutter packages that imply connecting to some google api (or else), there is some setup involved that is described on the package page.

It is really important to do all that's needed before the package can work, including getting an api key Google Cloud, activating Maps for Android and for iOS on it (if you need both). And then you have some setup to do for both iOS and Android on your flutter app.

It's all described in the link I provided, and you should follow their instructions rigorously. All it takes is one little setup error to stop the whole thing from working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I think solved it by enabling the **Maps SDK for android** and **Maps SDK for IOS** in the `GoogleMapsConsole -> APILibrary` section.

[Google map console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9HkU.jpg)

then **reinstall** the application and if you're using the emulator restart it as well.

Hope it could help you.